# Android, Signup button moves up

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new on android and its layout. I designed Signup screen but it has a problem. Problem is **When i start the data entry SIGNUP button moves up with keyboard and covers the Password field, it should stay on its place.**
 How can I fix it?
My XML code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="SIGN UP"
        android:textColor="#00aeef"
        android:textSize="22dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name" 
        android:inputType="textCapSentences">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name" 
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eemail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signupBtn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="SIGN UP"
        android:textColor="#00aeef"
        android:textSize="36dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing activity's `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in your manifest.

Ex:

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
    android:name=".SongPlayActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_song_play" >
</activity>
```

And if this not works then try different values for `windowSoftInputMode`.